# Kibana return results where a specific field is unique

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

So have been used to using GrayLog to build queries like this and struggling to get my head around Kibana so I need a few pointers to get me going.

I have an index that I want to search for various terms in a particular field. For example I want to search the index for the term **"*MFA*"** and this term will be in the **adaptorid** field. This returns some results so far so good but I would like to filter this a little more.

One field in particular that is of interest is **trackingid**, in fact it is actually the only field that I care about. The results that are returned can return multiple duplicate **trackingid**s for each matched **adaptorid**.

What I would like to do is dedupe the **trackingid** so that I can get a count of the unique **trackingid**. The **adaptorid** field really doesn't matter in the final results and is just used to identify a particular sub set of **trackingid** fields from the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Kibana 6.5+

Go to kibana -> **Visualize** -> Click on **+** icon -> Select **Data Table** -> Select your **index** -> Under Metrics select **Unique Count Aggregation** and your field **trackingid**-> Click on **Play Icon |>**

This will give you count of unique tracking Id's in you index. Now you can use kibana **Add a Filter** from top to filter **MFA** in **adaptorid**

Comment: Well that seems to work very well and it gives me a value in a data table. I know this wasn't part of the ask but now I see how this is performed in Kibana how do I see the data that is being used in building the value in the table?